# Menstrual Tracking Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, calendar

I am developing a calender which is for menstrual cycle calculator ,I have to highlight the days for the following phase,they are

1. Bleeding Days
2. Fertile Phase
3. Ovulation Day

**Data which i have for the process**

1. The user will choose the date when period starts
2. The menstrual range by default of 28 days

**Process by the data**

With the date of period started and the cycle range,the above mentioned formulas will be applied

for calculating three different range of dates

Using the range of dates,the highlighting of dates will be applied for the year and upcoming years

The calculation steps for all the ranges

**Bleeding Date Calculation**

Assume that user selected date as "a"
Assume the default period cycle as "X"

bleeding days=x + 3 days

**Fertile Phase Calcultaion**

**Fertile Phase I**

the formula provides the end date of the phase 1

phase I ranges from date selected and the end date of phase 1

Formula

b =[{a +(x-1)-19}]

**Fertile Phase II**

c=[{a+(x-1)-10}]

**Fertile Phase**

Range from (b+1) till (c-1) is fertile phase range

**Ovulation Day**

Particular Date=[(b-1) +{(c-b)/2}]

i am using [jqm calendar](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/f6xeE/)

Problem is: I can't figure out how to replicate the `highlighting of days` to all dates based on the calculation for all months

Comment: Well... This was my client's requirement. If you've any idea about above problem, then please help me. I develop even better things than this

Comment: Could you edit your question to give a better idea of what data you have so far, and what exactly the next step is that you're trying to figure out?  Is it a question about using the jQuery mobile calendar, or are you looking for help with your algorithms?

Comment: jQuery mobile calendar has been implemented successfully as shown in jsfiddle. I need help with algorithms where I can implement the code to highlight specific days as asked in the question.

Comment: I would suggest restructuring your question to eliminate the calendar control code, then, and make it clear what data you have, and what data you're trying to end up with.

Comment: I'm trying to build a calendar which is similar to this link http://www.kotex.com/na/period-planners/quick-period-calculator.aspx

Comment: Can't you simply add events to handle the highlighting? So if you have 3 bleeding days, simply make 3 events to represent them.

Comment: actually these above days is to be reflected on all the upcoming years so creating event for that would be lengthier process

Comment: @TehShrike i have re-framed the question ,Kindly help me if i am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to work out all dates for all months, you only really need to work out the next two events on each update of the calendar (since you may have up to two sets of events in one month but never more). When the user navigates to the next month, you can calculate the events for that month "on the fly".

You've already got the time spans between events from which to calculate future events. I've simplified your formulae to this:

```
var periodCycleDays = 28;
var fertilePhaseStart = periodCycleDays - 20;
var fertilePhaseEnd = periodCycleDays - 11;
var ovulation = (fertilePhaseStart-1) + (fertilePhaseEnd - fertilePhaseStart)/2;
```

With this, given an initial date, you can calculate the future events for any given month. All you need to do is work out how many cycles have passed between the initial event and the month that you're looking at. Then simply multiply all of your event time spans (variables above) by the number of passed cycles and add that number of days onto the initial date.

Here's an demo of how you might do this: http://jsfiddle.net/2sf4gfdr/